# Duplicate identifier 'Match' in TypeScript in GitLab Web IDE

Tags: typescript

I've already read multiple questions about this, but all of them seem to be about `node_modules` and say to not include that in the `tsconfig.json`, but my issue is in my own code.

I have 2 files, each with a class. My repo with these 2 files is [here](https://gitlab.com/Jump-RBX/Lobby/tree/master/src/server/modules). In the GitLab IDE when hovering over Match or Player depending on the file, it will say `Duplicate identifier 'Match'` or `Duplicate identifier 'Player'`. Is it because the file has the same name?

```
class Match {
    type: void
    players: object[] = []
    constructor(type: void, players: object[]) {
        this.type = type
        this.players = players
    }
}
```

[image: When hovering over "Match", a box appears saying "Duplicate identifier 'Match'"]

Comment: Works fine in VSCode if I checkout your repo

Comment: Please include a [mcve] showing just enough code to reproduce the error. Links to external sites are not adequate, since the contents will likely change, and/or they will become broken.

Comment: That code does not produce that error: [TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20Match%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%20void%0D%0A%20%20%20%20players%3A%20object%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(type%3A%20void%2C%20players%3A%20object%5B%5D)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.type%20%3D%20type%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.players%20%3D%20players%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D).

Comment: It doesn't produce an error when compiling, but the GitLab IDE says there's a duplicate identifier.

Comment: Looks like a bug in the GitLab Web IDE, and I don't know enough about how the Web IDE is implemented to investigate it.  I suggest you [file an issue there](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce).

Comment: Thanks, I’ll check if GitLab IDE’s TypeScript is broken.